# What should i do when a user have two account?

Tags: discussion

[Ideal Designer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/18632/ideal-designer) and [Ideal Designs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16924/ideal-designs) this user have two accounts and he is asking the questions using both two accounts. **Is this ok ?**

Below is the questions asked by him from different accounts

> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77181/omega-4-and-susy-and-sass-question
>
> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/bundle-exec-guard-ruby-error-in-omega-4-theme-what-error-means

So he have a chance to vote for himself and my question is what should i do now ?

Is already any option there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StackExchange Team can merge the accounts if its prudent to do so (you can make the request via the Contact Us link in the footer), but there's nothing wrong with having multiple accounts unless they're being used for fraudulent purposes. The user simply might not have realised they were using two separate accounts.

Currently neither of those accounts has sufficient reputation to vote so I wouldn't worry about it from that angle.

Lets give the new user the benefit of the doubt for now :)

Comment: how do we know if the user votes himself ?

Comment: The system reports suspicious voting activity to moderators automatically. The metrics for this are secret (to all but the devs), but rest assured if a pattern of abuse was to emerge, for any user, we have ways to take care of it

Comment: @Clive Took the liberty of clarifying this a mods can't do merges anymore.

Comment: @ MPD thanks, forgot about that

Comment: There are currently people doing this because their questions get downvoted.